# List index out of range (python)

Tags: python, list, indexing, range

I am creating a word generator for playing charades, and it works for about six words, then says "List index out of range."

this is my code:

```
def selection(word):
    while True:
        from random import randint
        sel = randint(1,10)
        print(word[sel])
        input("\nPress enter to select a new word.")

print("Type in ten words to add to the list.")
words = []
words.append(input("1st word: "))
words.append(input("2nd word: "))
words.append(input("3rd word: "))
words.append(input("4th word: "))
words.append(input("5th word: "))
words.append(input("6th word: "))
words.append(input("7th word: "))
words.append(input("8th word: "))
words.append(input("9th word: "))
words.append(input("10th word: "))
input("\nPress enter to randomly select a word.")
selection(words)
```

Comment: is there any specific reason you're importing `randint` repeatedly in the loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are currently picking a number between `1` and `10`, inclusive. Python lists are `0 indexed`, so you should be picking a number between `0` and `9`.

```
sel = randint(0, 9)
```

This is also a good place to use the [`choice()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) function. It picks a random element from a sequence (eg a list).

```
random_word = random.choice(words)
```

Comment: Also, if I wanted to make it so that the user could type in any number of words, how would I make it only select one of those words instead of one between 1 and some specified number?

Comment: @CharlieKimzey, `random.choice`. Notice you can just pass a list of words. You don't need to tell `choice` how many words there are.

Answer (score 0):

Also, not really an answer but you can do

```
for i in xrange(0, 9):
    words.append(input("{0}st word: ".format(i + 1))
```

Also

[random.choice](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice)

Comment: Could you please explain what that does?

Comment: will not work - since generate values from 0 to 8 including - 9 will be missed

Comment: This will print lines like "2st word"